# Calculate $1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}-\frac{1}{2^3}+...+\frac{1}{2^{10}}.$

Tags: calculus

So, this is simply a geometric progression, so rewriting I get $$1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}-\frac{1}{2^3}+...+\frac{1}{2^{10}}=1-2^{-1}+2^{-2}-2^{-3}+...+2^{-10}$$

$$=\sum_{i=0}^{10}(-2)^{-i}=\frac{1-(-2^{10+1})}{1-(-2)}=\frac{1+2^{11}}{3}=\frac{2049}{3}=683.$$

Which is incorrect. I used the formula for closed form of geometric sum: $$\sum_{i=0}^{n}k^{i}=\frac{1-k^{n+1}}{1-k}.$$

In my case $k=-2$ and $n=10$, plugging this in I get the incorrect answer. Can someone point out my misstake?

Comment: I think $k=\frac{-1}{2}$ not $-2$.

Comment: Try it with $k = -\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You correctly note that a finite geometric series can be computed as
$$ \sum_{i=0}^{n} k^i = \frac{1-k^{n+1}}{1-k}.$$
Note that the exponent in this series is *positive* $i$. (As an aside, do you know how to show that this formula is correct, or is it something that you have memorized?  If the latter, it would be a good idea to try to figure it out.)

Now, to evaluate
$$ 1 + 2^{-1} - 2^{-2} + \dotsb + 2^{-10}, $$
we can write
$$ 1 + 2^{-1} - 2^{-2} + \dotsb + 2^{-10} = \sum_{i=0}^{10} (-2)^{-i}. $$
In this sum, the exponent is *negative*, so we cannot directly use the formula.  But, using the fact that
$$ (-2)^{-i} = \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{i}, $$
we can rewrite the series.  Then the computation looks like this:
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{10} (-2)^{-i}
= \sum_{i=1}^{10} \left( -\frac{1}{2} \right)^i
= \frac{1-\left( -\frac{1}{2} \right)^{11}}{1 - \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)}
= \frac{2^{11}+1}{2^{11}}\cdot\frac{2}{3}
= \frac{2^{11}+1}{3\cdot 2^{10}}
= \frac{2049}{3072}
= \frac{683}{1024}. $$

Comment: After I rewrote all the terms from $\frac{1}{n^m}$ to $n^{-m}$, the exponent is negative. Arent those two equivalent? Why can't you do it my way?

Comment: Because $(-2)^{-i}$ is not the same as $(-2)^i$.

Comment: So, how do you calculate the sum $$1-2^{-1}+2^{-2}-2^{-3}+...+2^{-10}?$$

Comment: The computation is in the answer above.

Comment: Okay, so before I can use the formula, I have to manipulate the expression so that  $i$ is positive? As long as $i<0$ I can't use it? My question is, can one compute the sum, without rewriting $$(-2)^{-i}= \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{i}?$$ Yes, I know how to prove that formula. EDIT: Ok, now I get it, thanks a lot buddy!

Comment: In general, you can only apply a theorem in mathematics if the situation that you are working with satisfies the hypotheses of that theorem.  In this case, the theorem begins as follows:  if $k$ is a real number and $n$ is a natural number, then $\sum_{i=0}^{n} k^i = \dots$.  It does not directly apply to geometric series with negative exponents (though it can easily be extended to that case---do you see how?).

Comment: Yes, ofcourse the formula only holds based on those presmisess. Yes, it's extended by using the fact that a number $n$ to a negative power $-m$ can be rewritten as $$n^{-m}=\frac{1}{n^m}=\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^m?$$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, its a GP. But
$$\sum_{i=0}^{10}(-2)^{-i}=\frac{1-(-2)^{-11}}{1-(-2)^{-1}}=\cdots.$$
You actually evaluated
$$1-2+2^2-2^3+\cdots+2^{10}.$$

Comment: But why? Why did I do it wrong by just plugging it in to the formula?

Comment: @Parseval But you **didn't** plug it in to the formula $\frown$.